# Concerning Tor relays, what is the difference between ORPort and DirPort?

Tags: tor, ports

I'm setting up a relay and my understanding is that the `ORPort` is required to be open to relay traffic from the outside world but do I need to enable the `DirPort` too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you don't need to enable DirPort.  If you set the DirPort, your relay will also serve as a directory mirror.

As a directory mirror other relays can query you for information about other relays on the network (for example to get a list of relays for building circuits).

Note that enabling this can significantly increase your bandwidth usage (full directory listings can be fairly large) and you'll have a lot more incoming connections.  For example, one of my relays serving as a mirror has over 1200 incoming connections for dir requests and pushes an extra 10-20 Mbps as a result.

I believe the [BandwidthRate](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#BandwidthRate) option includes limiting directory traffic (which is separate from [RelayBandwidthRate](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#RelayBandwidthRate)).

If you want to just run a relay, it's fine to leave DirPort as 0 so you can dedicate as much bandwidth to relaying.  There are a lot of relays running as mirrors so I think the capacity for them is pretty good, but running one when possible is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is still listed within the torrc config file and I came here because I didn't see it within a netstat after enabling it. Here the information for that too:

DirPort is obsolet and has been removed: https://blog.torproject.org/new-stable-security-releases-03515-0449-0459-0465/

Therefore it is not needed and a "DirPort 9030" in the torrc has no effect on relays.